# Python: How do I call a specific variable from a function inside the class?

Tags: python

I have Basic question
How do I call a specific variable from a function inside the class?
let say I have this

```
class One():
    def fncOne():
        fileOne = "one"
        filetwo= "two"
        filethree= "three"

        return fileOne ,filetwo,filethree

fncOne() // Will call all of them together
```

But I want to call only one of them to print it fncOne().filetwo

Thank you,

Comment: Just do `fncOne()[1]` to get the second file

Comment: You are not relly returning 3 values, but actually a tuple with 3 elements. Those elements can be accessed by their index, which starts with 0. That is why `fncOne()[1]` works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your code is structured now, I don't think anything will happen at all. First, you made a class with a method inside of it, but the method has no "self" argument so you will get an error. Second, the "return" is not inside of the method.

Even if you fix where the return is, as soon as you instantiate the "One" object, an error will be thrown:

```
class One():
    def fncOne():
        fileOne = "one"
        filetwo = "two"
        filethree = "three"
        return fileOne, filetwo, filethree

a = One()
a.fncOne()
```

This will get you:
    TypeError: fncOne() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

However, if you take the method out of the class definition, the above comments are fine:

```
def fncOne():
    fileOne = "one"
    filetwo = "two"
    filethree = "three"
    return fileOne, filetwo, filethree

fncOne()[1]
```

That will return 'two' as you desire.

However, you want to keep the class so maybe what you need to do instead is:

```
class One(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.fileOne = "one"
        self.fileTwo = "two"
        self.fileThree = "three"

myObject = One()
myObject.fileTwo
```

That will return 'two' because 'fileTwo' is now an attribute of the class One.

Comment: Thank you Aya, When I use  global it works fine and I can call the value from any function in any class..  without the need for self or object. But I believe your solution is better then using global

Answer (score 0):

`fncOne` returns tuple (of three elements) in your case.

You can either index like this:

```
one.fncOne()[1]
```

... or use more pythonic tuple unpacking:

```
(_, filetwo, _) = one.fncOne()
```

Note that you seem to have number of issues in your code, like missing `self` in method definition.